# Angular access to form from a controller

Tags: angularjs

*It is not a question, i share a solution *

I need to access to my FORM from my controller to valid some input accroding to it value ( example, the ISO code should be in my ISO code list ... )

The question is not about how to valid or check the form or input but how to access to form properties ( $valid / $error etc), not to the input value (use ng-model for that )

```
<form autocomplete="off" name="formLocalisation">
      <input type="text" placeholder='countrycode'
               class="form-control input-md"
               ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="3" name="countrycode"
               ng-change="validLocalisationField('countrycode')"
               ng-model="countrycode" />
       <input type="text" placeholder='country name'
               class="form-control input-md"
               ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="3" name="countryname"
               ng-change="validLocalisationField('countryname')"
               ng-model="countryname" />
</form>
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Why do you think your controller is unable to access the form?

Comment: I don't know, what you want.

Comment: I guess OP is sharing his experience. In this case it would make sense to post solution as an answer and make a real question. In any case, the proposed solution is not really how validation should be done. It would be better to create custom directive.

Comment: It's not a question ... i share a solution after many search

Comment: @ Aakash. remove the $parent and try to access to the formLocalisation

Comment: why to down vote ?? i just want to share a solution that take me long time to found

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is another way without using $parent:

```
<form  autocomplete="off" name="formLocalisation">
    <input type="text" placeholder='Code ISO'
        class="form-control input-md"
        ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="3" name="countrycode"
        ng-blur="validLocalisationField(this)"
        ng-model="specimen.countrycode" />
</form>
```

you just have to initialize the form:

```
$scope.formLocalisation = {};
$scope.validLocalisationField = function (field) {                         
    if ( .... ) {
        $scope.formLocalisation[field].$setValidity("countrycode_valid", false);
    } else {
        $scope.formLocalisation[field].$setValidity("countrycode_valid", true);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After searchs and headache i share a solution that i found

You need to put $parent in the form name ! :

```
  <form autocomplete="off" name="$parent.formLocalisation">
      <input type="text" placeholder='countrycode'
               class="form-control input-md"
               ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="3" name="countrycode"
               ng-change="validLocalisationField('countrycode')"
               ng-model="countrycode" />
       <input type="text" placeholder='country name'
               class="form-control input-md"
               ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="3" name="countryname"
               ng-change="validLocalisationField('countryname')"
               ng-model="countryname" />
</form>
```

In the controller you can access to the form with $scope.formLocalisation:

```
 $scope.validLocalisationField = function (field) {                         
    if ( .... ) {
        $scope.formLocalisation[field].$setValidity(field+"_valid", false);
    } else {
        $scope.formLocalisation[field].$setValidity(field+"_valid", true);
    }
 };
```

source = http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cant-access-form-on-scope/679/18